# When I add a header in a listview I need to do position - 1 to access the backend list

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listfragment, listadapter

I have a `ListFragment` and a custom `ArrayAdapter`.
I do:

```
getListView().addHeaderView(inflatedHeader, null, false);
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(dataArrayList);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

It works but I noticed that in the `getView` method of the adapter it is called with position starting from 0, while the `onListItemClick` item when I click on an element of a list I need to do `position - 1` to get the corresponding item from the `dataArrayList` I passed in.
So basically I click on the first element of the list after the header and I get in the `onListItemClick` position == 1, and therefore I need to do `getListAdapter().getItem(position - 1)` in the method.
Is this how it is supposed to work or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: the position in onListItemClick  should start from 0, as i remember. Do you mean the item id? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView, android.view.View, int, long)

Comment: @onof: The position of the item in the list. It seems that the first item in the list is 1 and not 0 when clicking the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `getItemAtPosition(int position)` instead of `getItem(int position)` in your item click listener, which takes already in consideration headers and footers view

Comment: So instead of doing `getListAdapter.getItem` do `getListView().getItemAtPosition`? Always?

Comment: use the first parameter of the callback. Depending on which one are you using you should get either  a `ListView` object or an `AdapterView` object. Use it to access the underlaying dataset at position